# Java Set double value with all decimal point and get only 2 digit after decimal point

Tags: java, hibernate, decimal

In java , I have confusion about store and get double value.
Currently i am creating software where some accounting part included,i want to store calculated value same as they are calculated like 202.234234234212312 and while in display i want to display it as 202.23 in 2 digit after decimal point.
and in calculation i want to do calculation with 2,4 or 6 digit.

for that i have 2 option

1. Store value as it is calculated and in getter method of amount field, i can format it like.

   ```
   private Double amount;
   public Double getAmount() {
       DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");
       return Double.valueOf(df2.format(amount));
   }
   ```

but problem with this method is , it will get formatted number at all time i get amount. i can't get actual stored amount.

2. i can use 2 separate field for get and set.

   ```
   private Double amount;
   private Double amountFormatted;

   public Double getAmount() {
       return amount;
   }

   public Double getAmountFormatted() {
       DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");
       return Double.valueOf(df2.format(amountFormatted));
   }
   ```

so please provide better way to store and get decimal value, Thank you.

Comment: This is in your entity class?

Comment: yes this is in my entity class and serialize, deserialize request and response in json format. i want actual value for calculation and two digit value for display. but when i deseralize my json request that time also i get 2 digit value in first case

Answer (score 2):

First of all, all calculations involving money should be done in BigDecimal, not double. A double cannot represent quantities like 0.1 exactly.

Secondly, your `getAmountFormatted` should not return a Double but a String if it is only intended for output purposes.

Use the same amount variable for both methods.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you just want to get different format for same value, you can just have one variable and 2 get fields like this:

```
private Double amount;

public Double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public Double getAmountFormatted() {
    DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");
    return Double.valueOf(df2.format(amount));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an entity's job to provide formatted data for display: leave formatting to the code that is actually doing the displaying.  More to the point, it's not *your* job as the programmer of the entity class to 1) anticipate every future need for a formatted value, and 2) constantly update the entity class to provide new formatted values that you didn't (nay, *couldn't*) anticipate.

So just have the `getAmount` method return the raw unadulterated data:

```
public class Entity {
    private BigDecimal amount;
    public BigDecimal getAmount(){ 
        return amount;
    }
    //...
```

}

and eliminate `getAmountFormatted` from the entity.  When you want to display the amount formatted to two decimal places, just obtain the raw amount with `getAmount()` and format it right on the spot:

```
Entity e = ...;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
System.out.println("The amount is " + df.format(e.getAmount());
```

Here's a little story that illustrates why I think this is the way to go...

Suppose there's a *second* amount, `otherAmount` in your entity, that was included at the time the entity was created because someone thought it *might* be needed in the future.  And suppose that, because the field had no planned use at the time, you didn't bother to create a `getOtherAmountFormatted()` method to provide a two-decimal-formatted version of `otherAmount`.

Now the future arrives. The `otherAmount` field is now being used, and you need to start displaying it with two decimal places along with the original `amount`.  You know you're going to have to add the line

```
System.out.println("The other amount is " + ...
```

into the code that's displaying the amounts.  Only question is, how do you finish that line.  Do you **add into your entity class** a `getOtherAmountFormatted()` method and then write:

```
 System.out.println("The other amount is " + e.getOtherAmountFormatted());  // NO!!
```

Or do you **not touch the entity class at all** and just write:

```
 System.out.println("The other amount is " + df.format(e.getOtherAmount()); // Yes!!
```

The entity isn't the class that ultimately needs the formatted version of `otherAmount`, so it shouldn't have to change just to accommodate some entirely other bit of code that now happens to need a formatted version of `otherAmount`. Especially when that other bit of code can just get the unformatted amount, which the unmodified entity can *already* provide, and then do the needed formatting for itself.

Next scenario: in the further future, *yet another* requirement has come up to print those amount fields, but now with with *three* decimal places.  Are you going to add *yet more* methods into the entity class to provide three-decimal versions of the amounts (in addition to the ones already providing two-decimal versions)?  Or will you **not touch the entity class at all** and just write, at the point you need those three-decimal formatted values:

```
DecimalFormat df3 = new DecimalFormat(".###");
// ...
System.out.println("The amount in 3 decimals is " + df3.format(e.getAmount());
System.out.println("The other amount in 3 decimals is " + df3.format(e.getOtherAmount());
```

Comment: thanks @kevin Anderson, you are right. i can format fields as u suggest,but i  am using java as backend and angular as frontend , i want to send formatted data to frontend for display, i can put this type of format on angular side also but using different methodology on java and angular both side, i want to make on single side only for consistency